# How does auto-scaling work on Uffizzi Cloud?

Tags: docker, cloud, hosting, devops, autoscaling

Trying to understand how Uffizzi's auto-scaling works in general, anyone who's used this before give some insight?

Answer (score 1):

Uffizzi's underlying infrastructure auto-scales horizontally.  When you deploy your app as a container image you choose an initial amount of memory i.e. 0.5Gb, 1.0Gb, up to 14Gb.  When traffic increases to your app which takes the form of increased requests the CPU requirement also increases.  When your container hits 75% of the allocated CPU uffizzi automatically stands up another container and the workload is load-balanced between the two containers.  If demand continues to grow it will continue to scale with more and more containers.  If demand falls it will scale back down to the original container size setting.

When choosing your initial memory setting you are aiming for your steady-state requirement and you can rely on the auto-scaling for your surge demands.

Note that only the performance and enterprise tiers include auto-scaling.  The standard tier will not auto-scale with an increased workload and your app is likely to serve an error response under increased load.  Bumping up the Memory also bumps up the CPU allocation so if you want to err on the side of safety choose a slightly higher memory than you think you need.